# _UIVisualEffectBackdropView is missing from UISearchBar stack making 'Paste' button effectively invisible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

In my app I have a `UISearchBar` inside modally presented (as a `formSheet`) `UIViewController`. There is `searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` called on `viewDidAppear` as I need keyboard to be shown immediately.

I've noticed, that in some undetermined occasions I can't see a `UICalloutBar` to paste a text in search bar. Most of the times when `UICalloutBar` is missing are after switching fro and to the app back again to copypaste some text.

Also inspecting with 'Debug View Hierarchy' shows that whenever `UICalloutBar` is missing there also a layout warning present 'Position and size are ambiguous for `UIKBInputBackdropView`.'

UITextEffectsWindow and UIWindow looks like this:

[image: UITextEffectsWindow][image: UIWindow]

As you can see there is `_UIVisualEffectBackdropView` is missing from `UICalloutBar`'s stack. However if some text is present already `_UIVisualEffectBackdropView` is drawn correctly.

[image: _UIVisualEffectBackdropView]

The problem persists until complete app restart regardless of dismissing and presenting the other views. Sometimes it resolves by itself when the new text is paste over single space like on a last screenshot.

I'd be really happy if someone have any thoughts on workaround for this issue.

The problem's found on device under iOS 13, app built with Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation, no, unfortunately. However I've never seen this issue on iOS 14 device.

Comment: hmmm strange. I am facing this on iOS 14 :(